# Relative Namespace - SOAP Call - Liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty

We are right now on WAS 8.5 and are trying to move to Liberty. Our applications are using a lot of SOAP calls and among them, there is a one that is using a relative namespace that is raising an exception. I know that using a relative namespace is not recommended but we are the client not the producer. There is a way to handle that in WAS 8.5 by adding the parameter "com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.dsig.relativeNamespaceAllowed=true".

Is  there such a parameter in Liberty ? Otherwise, we are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liberty changed it's JAX-WS implementation from what was used with WAS 8.5, and it doesn't support the same behavior that this property allows. That being said it might be possible implement it, if it's a requirement for your application I suggest opening a support ticket with IBM. There have been other JAX-WS behavioral differences that have been brought into Liberty for users that have requested it through support, and this might be such a case.